# How can I prevent Rails `exists?` calling `after_find`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I am upgrading a project from Rails 2.3.2 to 2.3.15.  It appears that `exists?` may now be considered a finder, which means functions such as `after_find` are now callbacks from `exists?`.

In 2.3.2 `exists?` did not trigger a callback to `after_find`.  I am having trouble finding a readable changelog other than commits on github which explicitly names this change in policy.

Can someone confirm that `exists?` did not call `after_find` (should it be present) in 2.3.2 and it does in 2.3.15?

If this is the case, is there a clean Rails way to segregate the `after_find` call?  I need some code executed after a true find, not after an `exists?`.

As a temporary work-around, I am experimenting with making this the first line in my model's `after_find`:

```rb
return unless self.has_attribute?(:some_attrib_your_model_uses_in_after_find)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three ways to do this that I've found, none of them satisfactory but at least two of them will work reliably, even if they're surprising in design and can create some very subtle bugs down the road.

#### A) Return if an Attribute You'll Use is Missing

```rb
def after_find
  # What a flaky way to ruin your code:
  return unless self.has_attribute?(:some_attrib_your_model_uses_in_after_find)
  @amazing_pain = @some_attrib_your_model_uses_in_after_find + 1
end
```

#### B) Grep the Entire Callstack

*(and pray exists? is in there because you think it is)*

I'm ashamed to post this as an option, but it's good to see what you can do with the array of strings available to `caller`.  Let's just hope `caller` doesn't change the formatting.

Using 2.3.15 from the console, the callstack to my model's after_find() is:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:347:in `callback'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:1687:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:1687:in `instantiate'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `collect!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:665:in `find_by_sql'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:1539:in `find_initial'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/base.rb:696:in `exists?'
(irb):2:in `irb_binding'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/workspace.rb:52:in `irb_binding'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/irb/workspace.rb:52
```

#### C) Make the Model Eager-Load

Some people might want to do this, an the 2.3.15 ActiveRecord README hints at it:

```
after_find :eager_load, 'self.class.announce(#{id})'
```

I don't want to put any more burden on the DB than I must.  The point of calling `exists?` in many cases is to do a simple single-column lookup.  Performing eager loading of a whole model and potentially its associations just to do an `exists?` call is going to cause a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer help you at all?

[after_find callback broken after upgrade to rails3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661376/after-find-callback-broken-after-upgrade-to-rails3)

The head rails 2.3 branch should be close to what exists in rails 3. I think a lot of major changes like this occurred around 2.3.12 or 2.3.14. IIRC this was done to ease upgrades to rails 3.

Comment: No, but thank you.  I read that one before posting mine.  That poster was having trouble with UTF-8 conversions.